# The time zone of a parsed time zone naive timestamp, pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark

With the data frame, df, below:

| date_to_be_parsed |
| --- |
| "1980-03-23 12:32:12" |

After parsing the date as follows:

`df = df.withColumn("parsed_date", to_timestamp(df["date_to_be_parsed"]))`

I wonder what is the time zone of the parsed date? is it the system's time zone, and is there any way to check the time zone of a datetime column in pyspark?

Answer (score 0):

You can check current **timezone** by using `spark.sql.session.timezone`

```
spark.sql("set spark.sql.session.timeZone").show(10,False)
+--------------------------+----------------+
|key                       |value           |
+--------------------------+----------------+
|spark.sql.session.timeZone|America/New_York|
+--------------------------+----------------+
```

Comment: Thank you, but I'm asking about the time zone of a specific parsed date, which initially is time zone naive

Comment: if u parsed timezone in your code then its your session timezone and spark wont able to get the initial timezone if timestamp not created in this session. for this case u need to get timezone from source side.

Comment: so the parsed "1980-03-23 12:32:12" will have the spark session's time zone?

Comment: Correct, if u want to convert to any other timezones then use `to_utc_timestamp` function!